# Bot Framework Web Chat Read More ability

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I have a web chat in Bot framework V4. My response from QnA maker are very large at times. I want to put a functionality in place such that when i get a response i want to add a read more button and on click show the remaining text. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you let us know what you've tried so far?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the delayed response. Yes i am working on it. I found a solution to it. I split the text into characters of 300 and put them in an array. On click of read more. I displayed each of them until the array is empty. Guess what it worked..

Comment: Would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: Wait, are you still working on it or did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I did the below approach and it worked. Forgive my code formatting, if it is not proper.

I hooked the directline event and then modified the content

```
if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') 
{
    if (action.payload.activity.text != null && action.payload.activity.text != "") 
    {
                                if (action.payload.activity.text.length > showChar) {

                                    var content = action.payload.activity.text;
                                    var additionalIndex = content.substring(showChar).indexOf(".");
                                    var c = content.substring(0, (showChar + additionalIndex)).trim();
                                    var h = content.substr((showChar + additionalIndex) + 1, content.length).trim();
                                    var moretext = "Read More";
                                    var html = c + '<a class="ac-pushButton style-default" style="color:blue;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;" onclick=\'showMore(' + JSON.stringify(h) + ', this) \'>' + moretext + '</a>';
                                    action.payload.activity.text = html;
                                }
                            }
}
```